# The application crashes when receiving error from firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm asking you to help, I can't understand why the application doesn't fix errors from the firestore, there is a listener, but for some reason the application crashes, please help.

**Code Below:**

```
class LoadingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var prefStateFireBase: SharedPreferences? = null
    private var prefStateBd: SharedPreferences? = null

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoadingBinding
    private val db = Firebase.firestore

    private lateinit var webView: WebView

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityLoadingBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        if (!isOnline(this)) {
            val intent = Intent(this@LoadingActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        } else {
            prefStateFireBase =
                getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_STATE_FIRE_BASE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

            prefStateBd =
                getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_STATE_BD, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

            webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
            webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

            val stateFireBase = prefStateFireBase?.getString(Constants.SAVE_STATE_FIRE_BASE, "")
            val stateBd = prefStateBd?.getString(Constants.SAVE_STATE_BD, "")

            if (stateFireBase == "" && stateBd == "") {

                db.collection("database").document("check")
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener { document ->

                        if (document.data != null) {

                            if (document.data.toString().contains("h")) {
                                saveStateFireBase(document.data.toString().dropWhile { it != 'h' }
                                    .dropLast(1))

                                webView.loadUrl(
                                    setLink(
                                        document.data.toString().dropWhile { it != 'h' }
                                            .dropLast(1)))


                                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {

                                    val getLink =
                                        getUrlSource(
                                            setLink(
                                                document.data.toString().dropWhile { it != 'h' }
                                                    .dropLast(1)))

                                    if (getLink.contains("http", true)) {
                                        val intent =
                                            Intent(this@LoadingActivity, WebActivity::class.java)
                                        intent.putExtra(Constants.SEND_LINK_IN_WEB_VIEW, getLink)
                                        startActivity(intent)

                                    } else {
                                        val intent =
                                            Intent(this@LoadingActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                                        startActivity(intent)
                                    }
                                    saveStateBd(getLink)
                                }
                            } else {
                                saveStateFireBase("Nothing")
                                val intent = Intent(this@LoadingActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                                startActivity(intent)
                            }

                        } else {
                            saveStateFireBase("Error")
                            val intent = Intent(this@LoadingActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                            startActivity(intent)
                        }
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener {
                        saveStateFireBase("Error")
                        val intent = Intent(this@LoadingActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }

            } else {
                if (stateFireBase?.contains("h") == true && stateBd?.contains("h") == true) {
                    val intent = Intent(this@LoadingActivity, WebActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.SEND_LINK_IN_WEB_VIEW, stateBd)
                    startActivity(intent)
                } else {
                    val intent = Intent(this@LoadingActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun getUrlSource(site: String): String {
        val url = URL(site)
        val urlConnection = url.openConnection()
        val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(
            InputStreamReader(
                urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"
            )
        )
        var inputLine: String?
        val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
        while (bufferedReader.readLine().also { inputLine = it } != null) stringBuilder.append(
            inputLine
        )
        bufferedReader.close()
        return stringBuilder.toString()
    }

    private fun setLink(link: String): String {

        val pack = this.packageName
        val uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault().toString().substringAfter('"')

        return "$link/?packageid=$pack&usserid=$uuid&getz=${timeZone.substringBeforeLast('"')}&getr=utm_source=google-play&utm_medium=organic"
    }

    private fun saveStateFireBase(string: String) {
        val editor = prefStateFireBase?.edit()
        editor?.putString(Constants.SAVE_STATE_FIRE_BASE, string)
        editor?.apply()
    }

    private fun saveStateBd(string: String) {
        val editor = prefStateBd?.edit()
        editor?.putString(Constants.SAVE_STATE_BD, string)
        editor?.apply()
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    fun isOnline(context: Context): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val capabilities =
            connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)

        if (capabilities != null) {
            if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR")
                return true
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI")
                return true
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)) {
                Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET")
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this is happening and I can't test it

Comment: If the app crashes, find the stack trace in the Logcat tab and include it in your question.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Tyler asked for, and please also respond using @.